# I have this listview, i want webview for every row in the list, seperate webview for every item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

my apidemo.java

```
public class ApiDemos extends Activity {
private ListView lv1;
static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
    "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
    "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan" };
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , COUNTRIES));
}
```

}

and in my main.xml, i have ListView  with id:ListView01

want i really want is, a webview for afghanistan, and for rest countries.
on selecting them.

**PLZ rply soon.....URGENT......*********
i hv to submit the project IN MY SCHOOL_***_***

Comment: Sounds like you should have started your project earlier.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set up an OnItemClickListener for the listView:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Declare a new Webview at the top then within this OnItemClickListener set up a switch statment to assign the URL to the WebView depending on which item in the ListView was clicked. Then out side of the switch statment, but inside the OnItemClickListener, call on the WebView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thxs & sorry for the late rply... i was in hospital anywayz,
m not getting and quite confuse at switch statement depending on which items and m thinking of using a new textview instead of webview...

Comment: Ok so a switch statment is a basic java operation, similar to a lot of if and else staments. Look it up if you need need clearification. But you can use ether the postition or name of each element (using the OnItemClickListener) in the cases in the switch statement to set what you wanna set your webview (or text view) equal to. Your just using the OnItemClickListener to declare where you want the view to point depending on what item you click. Then once this is done, your just changing to the view

Answer (score 0):

Output look like WebView showing as listview row item.
Follow this guidelines.

Step 1.  main_relLay.xml
For adding scroll view and linear layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_relLay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#0B7A3B"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Description: ScrollView use for listview effect. Linear Layout have a dynamic content (WebView) of rows.

Step 2: row.xml
For ListView row item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_relLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F70925" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/row_webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Description: Create another xml for listview row items.

Java file :
Using LayoutInflater load view of row.xml for listview row.
And add this row.xml in main.xml linear layout its avaialable in scroll view, This is main linear layout provide listview effect.

Step A: LinearLayout relLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_relLay);

Step B: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Step C: View v_child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

Step D:  relLay.addView(v_child);